# JsArray not able to return length after receiving data from html5 storage

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, mgwt

i have to save JavaScript-Arrays which contains JavaScriptObjects into html5 storage.
The number of these JavaScriptObjects diversify in the arrays.
When iam reading out the saved JavaScripts-array out of storage i want to display the contained JavaScriptObjects which r in these arrays.
To do that i need the length of these arrays but its not possible because i get the error "something other was returned than an int" but ONLY when iam receiving the content of html storage. 
If i put objects in array and read the length after that it works like the example:

```
JsArray<Person> persons = JavaScriptObject.createArray().cast();
person.push(person1);
person.push(person2);
person.length();    // <---- this works
```

Here is first my JavaScript Object

```
public class Person extends JavaScriptObject{

protected Person(){}

    final public native void setName(String name)/*-{
         this.name = name;
    }-*/;   

    final public native String getName()/*-{
       return this.name;
    }-*/;
 }
```

Thats how i put objects into the JsArray and save it into storage

```
JsArray<Person> persons = JavaScriptObject.createArray().cast();
Person person = JavaScriptObject.createObject().cast();
person.setName("FirstName");
person.setLastname("LastName");
persons.push(person);

// create more person objects 2 - 3 and adding tham into the person array
persons.push(person2);
persons.push(person3);

// now save this array into storage
if(Storage.isSupported()){
    storage = Storage.getLocalStorage();
    storage.setItem("1",  new JSONObject(persons).toString());  
}
```

Now i want to read out the person objects from the array which is in storage saved.

```
  JsArray<Person> persons;

  if(Storage.isSupported()){
     storage = Storage.getLocalStorage();

      System.out.println("storage length : "+storage.getLength());  // <---- works gives 1

      for(int i = 0; i < storage.getLength(); i++){
           int keynr = i+1;
           String key = String.valueOf(keynr);
           persons = JavaScriptObject.createArray().cast();
           array =  JsonUtils.safeEval(storage.getItem(key)); // receiving the saved array from storage

           array.get(0).getFirstName();   // works it showes the name
           array.length();  // doesnt work
     }

}
```

I get the following error message:

> com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: Exception caught: Exception caught: Something other than an int was returned from JSNI method '@com.google.gwt.core.client.JsArray::length()': JS value of type undefined, expected int

So why is it not possible to get the length of the array after receiving the data of storage?
Is it even correct the way how iam doing it all?
Please help to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it and it works now!

1. save a JsArray into storage

   ```
        storage.setItem("1",  new JSONArray(array).toString());
   ```

2.Read that array out from storage

```
private JsArray<Person> array = JavaScriptObject.createArray().cast();

JSONValue jsonValue = JSONParser.parseStrict(storage.getItem(key)); // key is 1

JSONArray jsonArray = jsonValue.isArray();

for(int j = 0; j < jsonArray.size(); j++){
     JSONObject object = jsonArray.get(j).isObject();
     Person person = (Person) object.getJavaScriptObject();
     person.getName();
}
```